# Struts2 - Can i do this or it's a framework limitation?

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

What i would like to do its easy :

I have a menu that is loaded regardings the values of some variables. Let me show us the code :

```
<s:div cssClass="menu_table" id="loginContent">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not action.loggedOn}">
            <s:form action="checkLogin" theme="simple">
                <span id="err" class="menu_err">
                    <s:property value="error" />
                </span>
                <s:textfield name="nickname" />
                <s:password name="password" />
                <span class="menu_span">
                    <sj:submit targets="loginContent" value="Login" />
                </span>
            </s:form>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${action.loggedOn}">
            <s:form action="checkLogout" theme="simple">
                <s:label cssClass="menu_title" value="Ciao #{nickname}" />
                <span class="menu_span">
                    <sj:submit targets="loginContent" value="Logout" />
                </span>
            </s:form>
         </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</s:div>
```

The behaviour is very easy : if the action.loggedOn is true, i load a part of code, else another one.

Now, when i load each or the other, i can do an AJAX call (by using JQuery support) to the server, that change the value of the error variable (is a string) and the value of the loggedOn (which is boolean).

What i'd like to know (by using this frameworks) is if its possible execute directly this part of code on the server and reload this on client? (In less words i mean : is it possible to execute the jsp page server side (as for a standard request, but this time with ajax) and render only a small part of code to the client)

Or (as i think) i need to create the client-side function and repaint my divs (with JSON variables, for example, or others Jquery functions) due to the string-result after the ajax call?

Using JSF and other frameworks the first option is possible. Can i also do this with Struts? Hope my question is clear :)

Just curios.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way would be to create a new method in the controller which just returns a jsp only of the part of the menu (as the one you show in the question). You can make the ajax call and then load in the container of your menu the new jsp:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'yourUrl',  
    success: function(html){ 
        $('#menuContainer').html(html); }, 
    error: function() { 
        alert('There was an error!'); } 
    });
```

JSP is always executed in the server while JavaScript is executed in the client. But you can create several methods in the controller which can render only parts of the whole page and use them to update only one part.

**Edit: How to send json or html inthe same controller method**

```
<action name="HelloWorld" class="vaannila.HelloWorld">
    <result name="sendJson" type="json"/>
    <result name="sendHTML">/url/yourjsp.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and in your action something like this

```
public String execute(){
    if(json){
        return "sendJson";
    }
    if(html){
        return "sendHTML";
    }
}
```

Comment: That is something repainting what he has already suggested in his post

Comment: @umesh awasthi sure, and I think is the best way to do it :)

Comment: As i thought. So i need to return to the client the whole html for that page. Can you give to me an example about "return HTML code" to the client? Because for what i know i can just return JSON as result-type. Dunno if i can send a whole jsp page/code and include it to the client :)

Comment: @markzzz For returning the html code you will only have to creat a JSP with the code and set a <result>/url/myjsp.jsp</result> tag. It is the same as with json. if you set the type="json" in the result type you sent a json response, in case you don't specify anything it will take the default which is sending the html code from the jsp. Her you have a complete example: http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-hello-world-example-1.html

Comment: Nice :) Is it possible choose the return type duo to some string? for example : if my check function return SUCCESS i'd like to return a JSP. If my check function return FALSE i'd like to return just a JSON element. Is it possible?

Comment: @markzzz Sure you can, I've edited the answer with a simpleconfiguration to get that. You can return as many differnet things as results you have defined for the action.

Comment: So. I could not "repaint" the resource. I mean : if i write a single page called "designLogin.jsp" and i return this after an ajax call, and (on main page) i just include it, i don't need to rewrite code! That's i want understand by using this framework :)

Comment: @markzzz Yes you can "repaint" I don't understand why you think you can't do that.

Comment: Yes, ok! But, for example, if now i Need to return (with 1 ajax call) two different page and add them in 2 different div? This is impossible... Do you understand what Im looking for? :) Like add to `div1` the `page1.jsp` and on `div2` the `page2.jsp` (with 1 ajax call, one submit action and by using struts.xml)

Comment: @markzzz You'll have to make two ajax calls one for each jsp update. As they are asynchronous you can put one after another and they will be done "almost simustaneously". And I suppose that both jsp fragments are not the same so for that reason you'll need to invoke to different urls (one for each fragment), ad for that reason you need 2 ajax calls. You can do as many ajax callas as you want.

Comment: That's the limitation :) On JSF this is possible with 1 ajax call, for example. The same for GWT, and so on :) I just want to do an ajax call, and render many div according to the result of the ajax call :)

Comment: @markzzz maybe there's a way, but I have never seen something similar in struts

Comment: Maybe i can open a new topic, with this specific question :)

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge what you asking is not possible you have to go for repaint option what you have suggested in your post